# Scrapy playwright scrolldown and wait to load the html

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, playwright

I have a page

https://www.tradeinn.com/runnerinn/en/mens-shoes-trail-running-shoes/10005/s#fq=id_familia=10002&sort=v30_sum;desc@tm10;asc&fe=&pf=id_subfamilia=10005@&start=0

where products are automatically loaded after you scroll down (only 48 products showed initially). There should be in total about 630 products.

Here is my spider code. I always get only 48 results instead of 630+. Any idea why it is not loaded all?

```
import scrapy
from scrapy_playwright.page import PageMethod


class PicturesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'pictures'
    allowed_domains = ['www.tradeinn.com']
    start_urls = ['http://www.tradeinn.com/']

    def start_requests(self):
        yield scrapy.Request(url='https://www.tradeinn.com/runnerinn/en/mens-shoes-trail-running-shoes/10005/s#fq=id_familia=10002&sort=v30_sum;desc@tm10;asc&fe=&pf=id_subfamilia=10005&&start=144',
                             meta={'playwright': True,
                                   'playwright_include_page': True,
                                   'playwright_page_method': [PageMethod('wait_for_selector', 'div::boton_cargar_mas.color_runnerinn'),
                                                              PageMethod("evaluate", "window.scrollBy(0, document.body.scrollHeight)")]},
                             callback=self.parse)


    def parse(self, response):
        images = response.css('div.BoxImage')
        for image in images:
            image_link = image.css('img::attr(src)').get()
            image_description = image.css('img::attr(alt)').get()
            yield {
                'image_link': image_link,
                'image_description': image_description
            }
```

Any advise what should I change to get the whole content?

Comment: You can get all them without using any browser simulator like, playwright, selenium e.t.c.

Comment: Can you be more specific please how? But anyhow I would like to get it thru scrapy and scrapy-playwright.

Comment: What I meant is get data from that site simulating AJAX requests instead of playwright.

Comment: I could not find any request loading image links. I can only simulate request to get products info in json. But no links to pictures. I dont know from where they are loaded.

Answer (score 1):

The following is one way to get the images on that page - apparently only 398, not 600+  - it's even specified in the top breadcrumb - Trail Running Shoes(398)).
Solution is based on Selenium, you're welcome to functionalize it, OOP it, whatever, I'm only giving you the actual method of obtaining the images.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time as t

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
chrome_options.add_argument('disable-notifications')
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
chrome_options.add_argument("window-size=1280,1080")

webdriver_service = Service("chromedriver/chromedriver") ## path to where you saved chromedriver binary
browser = webdriver.Chrome(service=webdriver_service, options=chrome_options)
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 20)
actions = ActionChains(browser)


url = 'https://www.tradeinn.com/runnerinn/en/mens-shoes-trail-running-shoes/10005/s#fq=id_familia=10002&sort=v30_sum;desc@tm10;asc&fe=&pf=id_subfamilia=10005@&start=0'
browser.get(url)
pbody = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME, 'body')))
for x in range(14):
    pbody.send_keys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN)
    print('scrolled')
    t.sleep(1)
t.sleep(5)
images = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'img[class="imagen_buscador"]')))
print(len(images))
for i in images:
    print(i.get_attribute('src'))
```

Result in terminal:

```
scrolled
scrolled
scrolled
[...]
398
https://www.tradeinn.com/h/13855/138556150/nike-juniper-trail-running-shoes.jpg
https://www.tradeinn.com/h/13855/138552239/nike-react-pegasus-4-trail-running-shoes.jpg
https://www.tradeinn.com/h/13727/137276760/merrell-vapor-glove-3-shoes.jpg
https://www.tradeinn.com/h/13842/138429239/adidas-terrex-agravic-flow-2-goretex-trail-running-shoes.jpg
https://www.tradeinn.com/h/13855/138556425/nike-wildhorse-7-trail-running-shoes.jpg
https://www.tradeinn.com/h/13842/138429416/adidas-terrex-two-goretex-trail-running-shoes.jpg
https://www.tradeinn.com/h/13842/138429408/adidas-terrex-two-boa-trail-running-shoes.jpg
https://www.tradeinn.com/h/13855/138556423/nike-wildhorse-7-trail-running-shoes.jpg
https://www.tradeinn.com/h/13857/138574338/new-balance-410v7-all-terrain-trail-running-shoes.jpg
https://www.tradeinn.com/h/13857/138574792/new-balance-fresh-foam-x-hierro-v7-trail-running-shoes.jpg
https://www.tradeinn.com/h/13857/138574340/new-balance-410v7-all-terrain-trail-running-shoes.jpg
https://www.tradeinn.com/h/13789/137892027/adidas-terrex-two-boa-trail-running-shoes.jpg
https://www.tradeinn.com/h/13727/137276761/merrell-vapor-glove-3-shoes.jpg
https://www.tradeinn.com/h/13836/138368054/joma-trek-trail-running-shoes.jpg
https://www.tradeinn.com/h/13710/137107634/vibram-fivefingers-v-trail-2.0-trail-running-shoes.jpg
https://www.tradeinn.com/h/13789/137891690/adidas-terrex-agravic-flow-trail-running-shoes.jpg
https://www.tradeinn.com/h/13789/137892315/adidas-terrex-swift-r3-trail-running-shoes.jpg
https://www.tradeinn.com/h/13855/138552241/nike-react-pegasus-4-trail-running-shoes.jpg
https://www.tradeinn.com/h/13803/138030718/nike-wildhorse-7-trail-running-shoes.jpg
[..]
```

For Selenium docs, see https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/

Comment: You could have stuck with your api approach that you suggested in the first place. These are the first two ids used in an image link `item['id_modelo'][:5]`,`item['id_modelo']`. And, this is for the suffix of an image link `item['marca']`,`item['nombre_modelo_eng']` as well as the image description.

Comment: Yeah @SIM, I realize the urls can be constructed off brand/model and product name. Would have been a bit fiddly, and didn't have time to test etc. Less complex solution remains Selenium. Appreciate the upvote :)

Comment: Thank you both SIM and @BarrythePlatipus. Very useful both solution. I wanted to avoid selenium as I prefer Scrapy framework and it has in-build playwright which did not require any driver. Contruct the link came to my mind too, but I could not figure out quickly how so thank you again. If any chance you come to solution how to scroll with my initial code, please share it here. You both look very experienced scrapers :)